# How to make a sobel filter and apply partial derivatives and magnitude to an image

Tags: python, image, python-3.x, image-processing, sobel

I'm currently trying to implement sobel filter in python, in the code below i attempted to as wikipedia explained how sobel filter worked, hoever i haven't understood what the magnitude does to the image, and how to apply it

```
G_x = np.array([[1,0,-1], [2,0,-2], [1,0,-1]]) //Gx
G_y = np.array([[1,2,1], [0,0,0], [-1,-2,-1]]) //Gy

Gx = sg.convolve2d(f, G_x, "same", "symm") //f is a loaded image
Gy = sg.convolve2d(f, G_y, "same", "symm")
magnitude = np.sqrt(Gx**2 + Gy**2)
```

Sorry if this has been asked before, however the only questions i could find about this did not prove me any help

While on the topic, i've also been doing the same but with finite approximations, however i don't understand exactly how they differ as a result (maybe i will once i get sobel filter working), but if someone could explain that aswell i would be very happy.